Intrinsic definition of knot tricolorability
Knot tricolorability is defined on knot diagrams and it is easily to be seen to be preserved under Reidemeister moves, hence defines a knot invariant. Is there a way to define this notion on knots intrinsically, without projecting to knot diagrams?

Yes! A knot can be tricolored iff there is a certain dihedral representation of the fundamental group of the knot complement. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fox_n-coloring

You can define a tri-coloring as a homomorphism between two algebraic structures, and tri-colorability as the existence of non-trivial homomorphisms.
The algebraic structure here is called a quandle. They are sets equipped with two operators $\newcommand{\tl}{\mathbin{\triangleleft}}\newcommand{\tr}{\mathbin{\triangleright}}$ $\tl$ and $\tr$, satisfying

$a \tl (b \tr a) = a \tr (b \tl a) = b$,
$a \tl (b \tl c) = (a \tl b) \tl (a \tl c)$.
$a \tl a = a$.

We can regard $a \tl b$ as analogous to the group conjugation operation $b^a = a b a^{-1}$. Then $b \tr a$ is the inverse conjugation $a^{-1} b a$. Then the second law is saying that group conjugation is a homomorphism. In fact, for every group $G$, if we define the two operations as conjugations, we get a quandle $Q(G)$. (And actually these are all the possible equations you can add, in the sense that if you add any essentially new equational axioms in the definition of a quandle, $Q(G)$ will fail to be a quandle.)
Now recall the fundamental group $\pi (K)$ of a knot $K$ is defined as the fundamental group of its complement $\pi_1 (\mathbb{R}^3 \setminus K)$. We define the fundamental quandle to be $Q(\pi(K))$. Since fundamental groups are defined intrinsically, fundamental quandles are too. However it may be helpful to have an equivalent definition using a diagram: For each piece of curve on the diagram, write a generator. For each crossing involving the string $a$ going over another string (which will cut it into two curves $b$ and $c$), write the relation $c = a \tl b$. You need to fix an orientation to be completely rigorous but this should be clear. It's an easy exercise to see that this presentation gives a quandle isomorphic to the fundamental quandle. So for a trefoil knot, we have $⟨a, b, c \mid a \tl b = c, b \tl c = a, c \tl a = b⟩$. Try working out the entire quandle.
We also define a tricoloring quandle $Q_3$, with three colors, and $x \tl y = y \tr x$ is defined as the third color if $x \ne y$, and as the same color if $x = y$. Now a tricoloring is exactly the same as a homomorphism $Q(\pi(K)) \to Q_3$. Quandles can algebraically express many invariants elegantly, and for knots I believe is a complete invariant, up to chirality and orientation shenanigans which I don't recall.

Thanks! This is interesting.

Expanding what Cheerful Parsnip says:
Tricolorability is equivalent to $3$ being a divisor of the knot determinant. The knot determinant is equal to $\lvert\Delta(-1)\rvert$, where $\Delta(t)$ is the Alexander polynomial, which is intrinsic to a knot and does not depend on diagrams (it is the generator of the GCD of the 0th Fitting ideal of the first homology of the infinite cyclic cover of the knot complement! I have notes here). One can also characterize the knot determinant as being the order of the first homology of the double branched cover, which takes a lot less algebraic machinery. (Or the order of the twisted first homology of the knot using the unique nontrivial homomorphism $\pi_1(S^3-K)\to \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, if I remember correctly.)
